# Configuring PHPStorm with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm

This is [JetBrain Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Configuring+PhpStorm+to+work+with+a+VM#ConfiguringPhpStormtoworkwithaVM-1.DownloadandinstallVagrant)

states that Vagrant installation will create these shell files ( vagrant.bat / vagrant.sh ), which will be linked to by PHPStorm. However these files do not exist in my system.

Should I reinstall Vagrant or link PHPStorm to a different file?

Answer (score 0):

use terminal $ which vagrant
to find the programs root. Use this file directory to direct PHPStorm to Vagrant's executable.

Comment: What is your environment ? Do you have already vagrant or do you want create or load box ? What do you want to do exactly ?